# Trying to cross two dataframes, one with values the other with bools

Tags: python, dataframe, boolean, concatenation

I am trying to get a new dataframe from two source dataframes. The first would contain data, and the second would only contain True or False.
Both have the same column names, the same number of columns, and the same number of rows.

```py
import pandas as pd
data1 = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Name','Age'])

data2 = [[True,False],[False,True],[False,False]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['Name','Age'])

df3 = df1 X df2
```

df3 = [['Alex', ''],['',12],['','']]

I would like to get a dataframe where the fields are empty because in df2 they are to False and with the value of df1 when in df2 it is to True

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df3 = df1[df2].fillna('')
```

Example Output:

[image]

---

**Explanation**:

Since df1 and df2 have the same indexes; doing `df1[df2]` filters and shows the values that are true and add `NaN` for false.

`fillna('')` replaces all `NaN` values with empty strings.